# Separating Concerns in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I created a solution with 2 projects; one for my Models,ControllerFactories,Services to inject, and the other for my views and controllers.

I guess I have something wrong with my architecture as I realised I keep debugging and manipulating too much (not neat).
What will be the best approach in resolving this? My objective is to create an application that will enable future plugins without stress.

I'm new to MVC.

Comment: are you referring to asp.net mvc? as in microsoft's implementation?  Or are you creating your own mvc implementation?  what kind of application?

Comment: Yes it is microsoft's implementation of MVC. The difference is that I'm separating each concern to a different project. The challenge is, having the controller as a different project, the view is not referencing the Controllers in different project. How do I reference  the Controller from the View? Another is, should each project (Models,Controllers, and Views) have their separate Global.asax file? I am using StructureMap for DI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Dependency Injection (as you say: 'Services to inject'), you add a overhead to architecture, but this overhead is not bad. Sometimes when and app is too small, specially if is a web app, injection can create complex architecture, in long term the complex introduced by Dependency Injection, can be good for a project are changing constantly.

```
public class MyService: IMyServiceInterface { 
//Code contract implementation here
}

public interface IMyServiceInterface { 
//Code contract here
}

public class MyController: Controller {
      private readonly IMyServiceInterface service;

      public MyController(IMyServiceInterface service) { 
          //inject dependency
          this.service = service;
      }

      public ActionResult MyMethod() {
           //consume service here
           return View();
      }
}
```

Comment: I quite appreciate your explanation, but the question is "how"?

Comment: Have different projects aren't good approach. You need to mix MVC pattern with a N-tier approach. I suggest you to build a Service Layer. You need just one ASP.NET MVC project, in another project you should have Service Layer. Your MVC controllers consumes services, but you know services behind interfaces.